# Class not found in nameSpace

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit

I am trying to run a unit test with `PHPUnit`. But I get a `class not found error`. I have been trying for a long time now and I still couldn't find the problem.

This is the folder structure.

I have the Class `Calc` in `<base>/stats/cls` folder
and Test files in `<base>/stats/Tests` folder

`composer.json` file

```
{
    "name": "app/test",
    "description": "I am learning PHPUnit",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Fawzan",
            "email": "xxxxxx@xxx.xxx"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "*"
    }
}
```

`Calc.php` file

```
<?php

namespace stats\cls;

class Calc
{

    public function add($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }

}
```

`CalcTest.php` file

```
<?php     
namespace stats\Tests;

use stats\cls\Calc;

class CalcTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{


    public function testAddEquals()
    {

        $x = 10;
        $y = 20;

        $baseball = new Calc();

        $result = $baseball->add($x, $y);

        $expectedResult = $x + $y;

        var_dump($result);

        $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $result);

    }
}
```

`phpunit.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Unit">
            <directory>./stats/Tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

When I run the `phpunit` command I get the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'stats\cls\Calc' not found in /var/www/stats/Tests/CalcTest.php on line 26
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: If the autoloading is broken, show the `composer.json` file. Also, why is it broken in `BaseballTest` - a test class you didn't show.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong error line. I just edited it. I wil share the `compose.json` file.

Comment: FYI I don't think its a problem with the composer autoload. I have a dummy `assertTrue` which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have any autoloading for your own code in your `composer.json`, so bootstrapping `vendor/autoload.php` will only load the dependencies - in this case, PHPUnit only.

You still have to load the class you want to test. The easiest way is to define autoloading with Composer:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

As a quick workaround, you can still use `require_once()` at the top of your test (below the namespace line) to load the tested class, but this should only be shortcut to prove your code works. Getting used to adding autoload definitions to `composer.json` is easier in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the autoload to the `composer.json` and it worked.